# Spring Autowire bean NullPointerException during Groovy tests but works fine during Runtime

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am using the prometheus library for getting metrics of my Spring Boot application (REST API). I am using the library `io.prometheus.simpleclient:0.4.0` and I am including it in my Maven pom.xml. I am using the `Counter` and @Autowiring (I've tried both field and constructor injection) it to one of my own classes, like such

**MyCustomMetricsClass.java**

```
@Component
public MyCustomMetricsClass {
    @Autowire
    private Counter counterBean;

   public void myOwnMetricsMethod() {
       counterBean.inc();
       // do some stuff
    }
```

***THEN***, I am @Autowiring this `MyCustomMetricsClass` into my Service class, `MyServiceClass.java`, where it seems to run fine when I run my API locally using Spring Boot embedded tomcat on port 8080 (localhost:8080). I can hit endpoints and the metrics are being reported correctly at the actuator endpoint (localhost:8080/actuator/metrics). e.g.

*MyServiceClass.java*

```
public MyServiceClass {
    @Autowire
    private MyCustomMetricsclass myMetrics;


    public void genericServiceMethod() {
        myMetrics.MyOwnMetricsMethod(); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ONLY DURING TEST SCOPE (GROOVY)
    }
```

The problem is, when I run `mvn install`, which triggers the local Groovy unit tests I have written, I keep getting a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION. With the debugger, I can debug the Groovy unit tests and see in my Service class, the `myMetrics` variable is NULL. But I don't understand why it works fine at runtime, also, I have annotated the `MyCustomMetricsClass` as a **@Component** annotation, so it should be a bean being scanned by Spring Component scan.

This is a multi-module project ; with the structure below

```
my-project (root, contains root pom.xml)
   - my-api (module, contains RestController. has its own pom.xml)
   - my-service (module. contains service classes, has its own pom.xml)
   - my-model (module, contains all POJO/DTO model classes, has its own pom.xml)
```

Am I missing some dependency on my classpath? Why does it work at runtime but not during tests? (all my dependencies should have default scope) Is the autowiring broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the code from your unit test?

At a guess, you're using a mocking framework, maybe Mockito?

If this assumption is true, remember, your unit test won't be running up the full Spring context, so no auto-wiring will take place. You will need to inject mocks for the autowired components.

e.g.:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceClassTest {

  @Mock
  private MyCustomMetricsClass myCustomMetricsClass; 

  @InjectMocks
  private MyServiceClass myServiceClass;

  @Test
  public void shouldDoTesting() {

    myServiceClass. genericServiceMethod();

    verify(myMetrics).MyOwnMetricsMethod();

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Groovy/Spock. You were right , I was not mocking the above "myMetrics" variable that is used in my service class, but for some reason , its still not being Mocked properly 

I am mocking it like:
def myCustomMetricsMock = Mock(MyCustomMetricsClass.class)

Comment: Thanks, I was mocking it in Groovy, but was still getting NPE. I didn't realize that in groovy, or atleast in our codebase, we need to Mock the entire class under Test, THEN set all the mocks to reference all the member variables/fields of that class. When I did that, the NPE is gone and everything compiles. I 'll give you best answer since you pointed me in the right direction, thanks!